# calculate 5 star ratings in js array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that consist of feedback objects. Each object is a user feedback left for a product:

```js
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
0: Object { id: "1223", quality: 3, material: 4, … }
1: Object { id: "7342", quality: 3, material: 5, … }
...
```

Users can leave feedback for each category `quality`, `material`, ... out of 5.

I want to use the weighted average so on my site, I can show for example:

```
quality: 3
material: 4
```

This is [weighted average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196579/algorithm-used-to-calculate-5-star-ratings?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top) calculated by this formula:

```
quality: (5*0 + 4*0 + 3*2 + 2*0 + 1*0) / (2) = 3
material: (5*1 + 4*0 + 3*1 + 2*0 + 1*0) / (2) = 4
```

I want to add this my js project, so I loop through all feedback:

```js
const total = []
const feedback = [{
    id: "1223",
    quality: 3,
    material: 4,
  },
  {
    id: "7342",
    quality: 3,
    material: 5,
  }
];
feedback.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
  const score = arrayItem.quality
  total.push(score)
})
console.log(total.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0))
```

I am confused about how to do the calculation for each star, for example to get number of 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s, and 5 starts. How can I modify my code to return the rating result?

Comment: If you only want the weighted average and not the number of products in each star rating, then the total - which you have already calculated - is all you need.

Comment: I want the weighted average for each category, quality for example should be 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect all sums in an object and calculate the aveage on the fly.

If you need an array, take only the values.

```js
const
    feedback = [{ id: "1223", quality: 3, material: 4 }, { id: "7342", quality: 3, material: 5 }],
    types = ['quality', 'material'],
    result = feedback.reduce((r, o) => {
        types.forEach(type => {
            r[type] ??= { type, total: 0, count: 0 };
            r[type].total += o[type];
            r[type].avarage = r[type].total / ++r[type].count;
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, I am sure a lot of people will find this useful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

By changing the `total` variable from an array to an integer, we can add up the values first, and then divide them by the number of items in `feedback` to obtain the average rating.

```js
const feedback = [{
    id: "1223",
    quality: 3,
    material: 4,
  },
  {
    id: "7342",
    quality: 3,
    material: 5,
  }
];

let totalQuality = 0;
let totalMaterial = 0;
feedback.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
    totalQuality += arrayItem.quality;
    totalMaterial += arrayItem.material;
})
let avgQuality = totalQuality / feedback.length;
let avgMaterial = totalMaterial / feedback.length;
console.log(avgQuality);
console.log(avgMaterial);
```

Answer (score 0):

If every feedback has a quality and material rating the following code should work.

Since every feedback has a rating you can just use the .length of that Array to determine the total count of feedback. Then it's just a matter of adding them up since.
`(5*2 + 4*0 + 3*0 + 2*2 + 1*0) / 4 = 5/4 + 5/4 + 2/4 + 2/4`

```js
    const feedbacks = [
        {
            id: "1223",
            quality: 3,
            material: 4,
        },
        {
            id: "7342",
            quality: 3,
            material: 5,
        },
        {
            id: "7382",
            quality: 1,
            material: 2,
        },
    ];

    const feedbackCount = feedbacks.length;
    const weightedAverageFeedback = feedbacks.reduce((acc, feedback) => {
        acc.quality += feedback.quality / feedbackCount;
        acc.material += feedback.material / feedbackCount;
        return acc;
    }, { quality: 0, material: 0 });

    console.log("weighted average quality feedback", weightedAverageFeedback.quality);
    console.log("weighted average material feedback", weightedAverageFeedback.material);

    console.log("quality average feedback rounded up", Math.ceil(weightedAverageFeedback.quality / 0.5) * 0.5);
    console.log("material average feedback rouned up", Math.ceil(weightedAverageFeedback.material / 0.5) * 0.5);
```